# How do you disable the autofocus of a Razer Kiyo webcam on Mac?

Tags: windows, driver, webcam

The Razer Kiyo is not officially supported on Mac, but works anyway. Problem is: autofocus is not convenient, with the camera often jumping in and out of focus. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but in case people are searching for a free and easy solution for their home office setup, I finally found it.

[CameraController](https://github.com/Itaybre/CameraController) is free and works for the Razer Kiyo out of the box.

It allows you to disable autofocus and much more.

Comment: Unfortunately that software sometimes crashes my Mac in the middle of a tutoring session if I have run it in advance to turn off autofocus.

Answer (score 3):

This thread *[How do you disable the autofocus of a webcam in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/79995/how-do-you-disable-the-autofocus-of-a-webcam-in-os-x)*
, on SuperUser, had a similar question, but the answers did not help.

The only way I found to work requires **access to a computer running Windows** and is this:

- Connect the webcam to a computer running Windows. I did this in Bootcamp.
- Windows will detect the webcam and then offer to install Razer Synapse.
- Install Razer Synapse (it has an option to sign in as Guest to avoid being forced into creating an account.)
- In Synapse, find the Kiyo and open its *advanced settings*, then:

  - Disable autofocus (tick off the 'auto' checkbox.)
  - Set the focus value by hand. A value around 190 seems to do it.
  - Apply the settings.

The new settings are saved into the webcam itself, so they'll work in macOS. Reboot into macOS.

*(Between four Windows updates, installing and testing, this took me fifty minutes. Sigh. But you might have better luck.)*

Some websites recommend using OBS to do this, but:

- In Windows, it'll offer the exact same configuration modal as Synapse;
- In macOS, OBS will not offer any configuration modal.

---

EDIT: [Webcam Settings](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) ($7.99) did work for me on Mac.